# Wordpress messing up rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.app.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/app/
RewriteRule (.*)            /app/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^app.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/app/
RewriteRule (.*)            /app/$1
```

The problem: app.domain.com is working without problems, but as soon as you add a subfolder like app.domain.com/folder you get the Wordpress tag page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you show the actual url you put into your browser and the url you are redirected to, then you are more likely to get a useful answer, as it is quite difficult to guess what is happening without that information

Comment: do you have two wordpress installations? if so try to put another .htaccess on the app.domain.com/ root directory like this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/app/
RewriteRule (.*)            /app/$1
```

Which says that if the URL does not start with /app/ (which /folder doesn't) it must be rewritten to /app/folder. After that rewrite the RewriteRules will be processed again, and the wordpress section will find that folder doesn't exist and fire up wordpress for you.

The way to resolve this issue is to change the last block to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?app\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/app/
RewriteRule .? app%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This tells apache it may only rewrite to /app/folder if /folder does not exist.

(and you can remove the whole stuff for app.domain.com, this block handles both www.app.domain.com as well as app.domain.com